# Apollo GraphQL loading query

Tags: next.js, apollo, apollo-client

I am using Apollo GraphQL to fetch posts to populate a next js project.

The code I currently have works but I would like to implement the loading state of useQuery instead of what I have below.

This is the index (Posts page if you will)

```
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import Post from "../components/Post";
import client from "./../components/ApolloClient";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const POSTS_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    posts {
      nodes {
        title
        slug
        postId
        featuredImage {
          sourceUrl
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const Index = props => {
  const { posts } = props;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="grid">
          {posts.length
            ? posts.map(post => <Post key={post.postId} post={post} />)
            : ""}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

Index.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const result = await client.query({ query: POSTS_QUERY });

  return {
    posts: result.data.posts.nodes
  };
};

export default Index;
```

Then it fetches an individual Post

```
    import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import { withRouter } from "next/router";
import client from "../components/ApolloClient";

import POST_BY_ID_QUERY from "../queries/post-by-id";

const Post = withRouter(props => {
  const { post } = props;

  return (
    <Layout>
      {post ? (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="post">
            <div className="media">
              <img src={post.featuredImage.sourceUrl} alt={post.title} />
            </div>
            <h2>{post.title}</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
    </Layout>
  );
});

Post.getInitialProps = async function(context) {
  let {
    query: { slug }
  } = context;
  const id = slug ? parseInt(slug.split("-").pop()) : context.query.id;
  const res = await client.query({
    query: POST_BY_ID_QUERY,
    variables: { id }
  });

  return {
    post: res.data.post
  };
};

export default Post;
```

Whenever I have tried to use the useQuery with '@apollo/react-hooks' I always end up with a data.posts.map is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `useQuery`, you should not destructure the data like `result.data.posts.nodes` because the data field will be `undefined` and `loading` is true for the first time calling. That why you got an error `data.posts.map is not a function`. Then if your query fetch data successfully, the `loading` field will be false. 
You can try it:

```js
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import Post from "../components/Post";
import client from "./../components/ApolloClient";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks"
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const POSTS_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    posts {
      nodes {
        title
        slug
        postId
        featuredImage {
          sourceUrl
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const Index = props => {
  const { posts } = props;
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(POSTS_QUERY);
  
  if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>
  if (error) return <div>Error</div>
  
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="grid">
          {data.posts.nodes.length
            ? data.posts.nodes.map(post => <Post key={post.postId} post={post} />)
            : ""}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Comment: I have amended my answer, I'm not sure how to resolve the individual post page.

Comment: @HeyImArt You can do the same way to handle fetching data for individual post page.

Comment: So instead of the initialprops, I move those variables and pass in the loading, error and data to the new useQuery, the return the post ?

Comment: @HeyImArt You can use ```useQuery``` inside your component and pass ```postID``` as its variable to fetch the post data.

Comment: Sorry Michael, I'm still new to all this - I can't get it working. I tried moving it into the component then calling that component into the page within <Layout> but it renders nothing now.

Comment: What did you get from ```POST_BY_ID_QUERY```? An error or ```undefined```? @HeyImArt

Comment: I got undefined